# $_FILES Array Name Assignment

Tags: php

I couldn't find any duplicate questions but apologies if there is one.

For multiple PHP file uploads, is there anyway of naming the array indexes.
E.g.

```
<input type='file' name='file['file1']'>
```

So, instead of collecting data via this:

```
$_FILES['file'][0]
```

You get it via this:

```
$_FILES['file']['file1']
```

Comment: Did you try to do this?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You want to use `name="file['file1']"` or `name='file["file1"]'`.

Comment: this meaning what I wrote? Yes and it didn't work, hence I'm trying to find out if and how it is possible!

Comment: @ComFreek - the HTML is written within a PHP echo

Comment: @DorianHuxley: The resultant HTML still has to be valid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type='file' name='file[file1]' />
<input type='file' name='file[file2]' />
<input type='file' name='file[file3]' />
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$_FILES['file'][file1];
$_FILES['file'][file2];
$_FILES['file'][file3];
// and so on...
```

Comment: Works pefectly, it was just the removal of apostrophes

Comment: @Dorian: What prevented you from researching this topic in the PHP manual? This feature is widely documented therein, saving you from having to ask and us from having to answer...

Comment: I don't know, either I'm just extremely lazy and leach from others whenever and wherever possible, or I looked, tried and could not find it, presumably due to using incorrect terminology. (Hint: It's the latter).

Comment: @DorianHuxley: You don't need to "look". It's right there on the pages about forms, which you should have read _in entirety_ in order to understand PHP's support for the feature. You know what a "form" is? You did not read the whole page on forms when you couldn't immediately see the one specific thing you were looking for. So, are we _sure_ that it's the latter?

Comment: No, in all honesty I did not read the entire thing. I don't think anyone does. What I think is the case here is that someone is having a  power trip and attempting to belittle people as much as possible. You were learning once too.

Comment: please lock this post.

EDIT: I am however, grateful for the time and effort you put into replying and helping.

Comment: No, I'm not on a "power trip", nor am I out to belittle you: I am trying to help you to be a better software developer and a more useful denizen of SO. When I was learning, I read the documentation. I read the manual cover to cover, because _that's what it's there for_. I don't understand why nobody bothers to do this any more. :( I suppose it's because nowadays you can just go on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

The PHP manual has several examples of this on [the relevant page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php); it goes on to explain:

> PHP also understands arrays in the context of form variables (see [the related faq](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)).

The "related FAQ" says:

> It's also possible to assign specific keys to your arrays:
>
> ```
> <input name="AnotherArray[]" />
> <input name="AnotherArray[]" />
> <input name="AnotherArray[email]" />
> <input name="AnotherArray[phone]" />
> ```
>
> The `AnotherArray` array will now contain the keys `0`, `1`, `email` and `phone`.

We can see here that, by analogy, you should name your file field `file[file1]`. So:

```
<input type="file"
       name="file[file1]"
       title="A description of the field should go in here"
/>
```

---

**Use the documentation.** It is there to help you.

Comment: Nice formatting @Lightness, you are spending too much time formatting your answer, good for you (Y)

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways of doing this:

1. if HTML is:

`<input type='file' name='file[file1]' />`

`<input type='file' name='file[file2]' />`

Then PHP should be:

```
$_REQUEST['file']['file1'];
$_REQUEST['file']['file2'];
```

1. if HTML is:

`<input type='file' name='file[]' />`

`<input type='file' name='file[]' />`

Then PHP should be:

```
$_REQUEST['file'][0];
$_REQUEST['file'][1];
```

For more information kindly read the documentation : [this new one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) and [this old one too](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)